# NSManagedObjects inheritance primary key

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, core-data

in my data model i have to maintain some primary key system to be synchronize servers database system

so i have `ATEntity : NSManagerObject`
ATEntity -> an abstract class just have pk (primery key) property

and there is `ATBook : ATEntity` all good;
ATBook -> has many properties

now i need `ATCatalogBook : ATEntity` 
ATCatalogbook -> has some more properties with ATBook properties

in this system all properties are optional except pk

problem is that i am trying to create and save ATCatalogBook

```
NSManagedObjectContext
- (void)insertObject:(NSManagedObject *)
- (BOOL)save:(NSError **)error;
```

save gives me `NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1570`

when i inherit ATCatalogBook from directly ATEntity there is no error but i cant do inheritance

how must i do inheritance on NSManagedObjects ?

Comment: There's no reason you couldn't have multiple inheritance. You're saying this doesn't work: ATCatalogBook -> ATBook -> ATEntity right?

Comment: i know it should work but yet it does not work